# running multiple node tasks in parallel

Tags: node.js

I am trying to build a Node app that does two things:

1. Walks the file system processing specific files, storing objects in a list.
2. Walks that list, batching up objects and storing them in an AWS service.

Right now I'm doing this sequentially with success, but would like to parallelize if possible.  Normally I would use threads for something like this, but I'm not sure that's the right approach in Node.  I've started something with https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-parallel, but it's not working and I wonder if this is even doable.

Any suggestions and/or pointers to doco/examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) library. It has many useful methods like [each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each), [map](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map), and [parallel](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.